# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse" even though parsed json files are identical

Tags: javascript, json

I am a beginner. I started learning async javascript. I have encountered this
 error when I was trying to parse through data from 3 different JSON files.
The files are nearely identitical. I even exchanged their data and still luigi file cannot be parsed. however other files get parsed even though the data in them was exchanged.

```
//javascript File

const getTodos = (resource,callback) => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange',()=>{
    console.log(1);

    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status ===200)
    {
        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
        console.log(request,data);
        callback(undefined,'could not fetch data');
    }
    else if(request.readystate === 4)
    {
        callback('could not fetch data',undefined);
    }
    });

    request.open('GET',resource);

    request.send(); 
    };


        getTodos('todos/luigi.json', (err,data) => {
        console.log(data);
        getTodos('todos/mario.json', (err,data) => {
        console.log(data);
        getTodos('todos/browser.json',(err,data) => {
        console.log(data);
});
});    
});
```

Mario JSON file

```
[{"text":"Make fun of browser","author":"Mario"},
    {"text":"Make a painting","author":"Monalisa"},
    {"text":"teach DBMS","author":"Manisha"}]
```

Luigi JSON file

```
[{"text":"Be a side kick","author":"Developers"},
    {"text":"Green Mustache","author":"designers"},
    {"text":"lead second","author":"devlopers"}]
```

Browser JSON file

```
[{"text":"Beat Up Mario","author":"Red"},
    {"text":"Kidnapp Princess","author":"Yellow"},
    {"text":"Debut in next game","author":"Pink"}]
```

ALl Json files are getting parsed except for luigi.json file
that error is only present when I try to parse luigi.json file

Comment: The Luigi JSON in the question is just fine. Note that you're calling your callback with `undefined` and an error even on success. Also note you have a type in your `else`, `readystate` instead of `readyState`.

Comment: And just for what it's worth, I'd use `fetch` rather than `XMLHttpRequest` (you're clearly targeting modern environments, given the arrow function you're using).

Comment: Why not trying logging `request.responseText` before it gets parsed.